# Github trying to upload files and obtaining a series of errors

Tags: git, github

I am using RStudio and I have a number of files I want to upload using the shell access with RStudio.

I open my project and select Git/SVN (in RStudio Project Options).

The origin is set at: git@github.com:msmith01/master_msmith01.github.io.git

I want to upload all files in my:

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Matt/Documents/msmith01.github.io"
```

Where I have the following:

```
> list.files()
 [1] "~$tup Academic site.docx" "="                       
 [3] "config"                   "config.toml"             
 [5] "content"                  "index.Rmd"               
 [7] "msmith01.github.io.Rproj" "public"                  
 [9] "resources"                "Setup Academic site.docx"
[11] "static"                   "themes"
```

In the shell access I run:

```
PATH=$PATH” C:\Program Files\Git\cmd”

git add .
```

Then I run:

```
git commit -m "myNewUpload"

On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 6 and 5 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Running

```
git pull
```

I type in some access code and get the following:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Matt/Documents/msmith01.github.io/=/.ssh/id_rsa':
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

The files should replace the files in https://github.com/msmith01/master_msmith01.github.io

The thing is, that I last commited to this repo 5 months ago and I have made significant changes since then, therefore I don't understand the error `nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: From the error message it sounds like your two repositories are unrelated (the error message literally states that). Are you sure you are in the correct directory? What does the history in your local directory look like compared to the repository on GitHub? Any chance that you ran `git filter-branch` or similar in your local repo?

Comment: I get this when I run `$ git filter-branch
Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.`

Comment: I did **not** tell you to run `filter-branch`, I merely asked if you had used it. Because it might explain the error you see on push. _But_ if `filter-branch` complains about unstaged changes, then `git status` cannot tell you that your working copy is clean. Somethings not right here. Pleas double-check that you are in the correct directory, that you do not have any nested git-inside-git-repositories, or that your `.gitignore` is somehow ignoring everything.